Как исправить ошибку с аргументами в python?
class KijijiClient:
def __init__(self, chat_id):
    self.chat_id = chat_id
    self.session = requests.session()
    self.session.headers.update({
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    })



    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'parse_kijiji')
def handle_kijiji_parsing(call):
    chat_id = call.message.chat.id
    kijiji = KijijiClient(chat_id)
    if kijiji.create_session():
        if kijiji.authirize("email", "password"):
            bot.send_message(chat_id, "Authorized successfully. Starting to parse...")
            kijiji.parse_page("https://www.kijiji.ca/b-buy-sell/canada/c10l0")
            bot.send_message(chat_id, "Parsing completed. Check the results.")
        else:
            bot.send_message(chat_id, "Authorization failed. Check credentials or site access.")
    else:
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "Failed to create a session. Check network and site availability.")

Вот такая ошибка:
Ошибка при обработке запроса:
KijijiClient.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given


Табуляции исправьте в коде. И полный трейс ошибки покажите, а не одну фразу. Полный трейс ошибки прямо в вопросе должен быть.

Это вся Ошибка, которая выводится

Вы что-то лишнее передаёте при создании объекта класса‍♀️

Там много строк должно выводиться с цепочкой вызовов. Если def __init__ у вас действительно без отступа, то он просто не попал внутрь класса. Либо у вас код не тот, что вы показали вообще. Но в любом случае код с такими отступами просто не скомпилируется, до ошибки запуска дело не дойдёт.
